# Failed to collect dependencies at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc:ImpalaJDBC41:jar:2.6.4.1005

Tags: java, maven, impala

I have added the below plugin and dependency in my pom.xml file

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-external</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/../lib/ImpalaJDBC41.jar</file>
                            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                            <groupId>com.cloudera.impala.jdbc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ImpalaJDBC41</artifactId>
                            <version>2.6.4.1005</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudera.impala.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ImpalaJDBC41</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4.1005</version>
        </dependency>
```

but pipeline job failed with error:

```
*[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project data-management: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.core:data-management:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.cloudera.impala.jdbc:ImpalaJDBC41:jar:2.6.4.1005: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.cloudera.impala.jdbc:ImpalaJDBC41:jar:2.6.4.1005: Could not transfer artifact com.cloudera.impala.jdbc:ImpalaJDBC41:pom:2.6.4.1005 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [jcenter (http://jcenter.bintray.com, default, releases+snapshots)] -> [Help 1]*
```

I have added ImpalaJDBC41:jar in lib folder and version is also same